# Using RFID and SD card Reader at the same time with SPI and ESP32 not working

Tags: esp32, spi, rfid, arduino-esp8266, arduino-esp32

I am trying to use the ESP32 Dev Kit V1 with the MISO, MOSI, and CLK connected in parallel with the sd reader and RFID reader. If I unplug the SD card reader, the RFID reader works. When I plug the SD card in, it initializes correctly but the RFID does not scan or send any information for that matter.

```
/*
 * Rui Santos 
 * Complete Project Details http://randomnerdtutorials.com
 */

#include <MFRC522.h> // for the RFID
#include <SPI.h> // for the RFID and SD card module
#include <SD.h> // for the SD card

// define pins for RFID
#define CS_RFID 32
#define RST_RFID 33
// define select pin for SD card module
#define CS_SD 26

// Create a file to store the data
File myFile;

// Instance of the class for RFID
MFRC522 rfid(CS_RFID, RST_RFID); 

// Variable to hold the tag's UID
String uidString;

// Instance of the class for RTC


void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero
  
  // Init SPI bus
  SPI.begin(); 
  // Init MFRC522 
  rfid.PCD_Init(); 

  // Setup for the SD card
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if(!SD.begin(CS_SD)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // Setup for the RTC  
}

void loop() {
  //look for new cards
  digitalWrite(CS_SD, HIGH);
  if(rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    readRFID();
    logCard();
  }
  delay(10);
}

void readRFID() {
  rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial();
  Serial.print("Tag UID: ");
  uidString = String(rfid.uid.uidByte[0]) + " " + String(rfid.uid.uidByte[1]) + " " + 
    String(rfid.uid.uidByte[2]) + " " + String(rfid.uid.uidByte[3]);
  Serial.println(uidString);
 
}

void logCard() {
  // Enables SD card chip select pin
  digitalWrite(CS_SD,LOW);
  // Open file
  myFile=SD.open("DATA.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  // If the file opened ok, write to it
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("File opened ok");
    myFile.print(uidString);
    myFile.print(", ");   
    
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("error opening data.txt");  
  }
  // Disables SD card chip select pin  
  digitalWrite(CS_SD,HIGH);
}
```

I have been on this for 7 hours, and tried many different things such as using the VSPI and HSPI buses, pull down/pull up resistors on cs pins, changing library properties, adding a resistor connecting the MOSI of the SD to the MOSI of the RFID. Nothing has worked. This is for a senior design project where I am integrating it into a much larger project. I have also tried other Stack Overflow solutions but got nowhere. I just need the basics to work then I can use it for my entire project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: some SD card modules block the SPI bus

Comment: Both libraries using the SPI object directly. Maybe try to add `SPIClass vspi ;` to create an instance of `vspi` at global level, and replace `SD.begin(CS_SD)` with `SD.begin(CS_SD, vspi)`.

Comment: Don't tag `arduino-esp8266` when you are actually using an ESP32.

Comment: It was my cheap SD card reader. Got a new Adafruit one and it works! I also had to add a backslash before the file name when opening